# reading array key values with a keyname

Tags: javascript, arrays

Just an easy question, I have this code:

```
$("#renderBtn").click(
    function () {
        var data =  {"first":[20000, 14000, 12000, 15000, 18000, 19000, 22000], "second":[12000, 11000, 18000, 12000, 19000, 14000, 26000]}
        labels =  ["sunday", "monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday"];
            for ( x in data) {
                console.log(x);
                console.log(data.x);
                console.log(data.first);
            }
        }
);
```

as a result `x` is array key names which are "first" and "second", I can get values by calling `data.first` but the return out of `data.x` is `undefined` , how I can get values by calling data from x ???

Comment: Use bracket notation: `data[x]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Comment: thanks beacket works !

Answer (score 0):

You have to use two for loops one for data.first and another data.second beacuse your data is an object. for loop is used to loop through arrays.
for ( const x in data.first){console.log(data.first[x]);}
You shoud get the values